# Ordering content on webpage with bootstrap row's and col's push and pull

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question regarding bootstrap's grid model.
I have a row containing three divs, and here is how I want it to look in the different views.

**Mobile:**

```
all divs with xs-col-12 
div2 on top
div1 second 
div3 last
```

**Tablet:**

```
div1 col-sm-6 left (this is the main content)
div2 col-sm-6 right top
div3 col-sm-6 right bottom
```

**Desktop:**

```
div1 col-md-8 left (Still the main content)
div2 col-md-4 right top
div3 col-md-4 right bottom
```

Div1 is the main content on the page, and div2 and 3 are a sidemenu.

Code below is as far as i got..

```css
.div1{  
 background-color: red;
 height: 800px;
}
.div2{
 background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
}
.div3{
 height: 200px;
 background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  
 <div class="div2 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-8">div2</div>
 <div class="div1 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6 col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">div1</div>
 <div class="div3 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6 col-md-4 col-md-push-8">div3</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the order you want without changing the markup I believe you'll need to float divs 2 and 3 right, which would require a custom media query. (I've never seen classes in boostrap like `col-md-right`, `col-sm-left`, though you could add them.)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74f2bq0z/)

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    div.div1{
        float: left;
        right: 0;
    }
    div.div2 {
        float: right;
        left: 0;
    }
    div.div3 {
        float: right;
        left: 0;
    }
}
```